# AccessDeniedError at /auth/convert-token (access_denied) Your credentials aren't allowed <oauthlib.Request SANITIZED>

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vuejs3

I am using Django 4.0 with python 3.9 and I installed `drf-social-oauth2` in my app. I was using the now depreciated gapi Oauth2 for google login and it worked fine. Then I started getting warnings in my console that it'll not be in use for some time to come so I changed to the new google Identity Service(gsi client). What I used to get from gapi was an access_token which I use to verify users on my backend. now I get a credential jwt which I'm supposed to decode to get user details.

when I send this code to the `/auth/convert-token/` end point, I get `AccessDeniedError at /auth/convert-token (access_denied) Your credentials aren't allowed <oauthlib.Request SANITIZED>`

all my details are correct and I'm stuck.

[Tested this using vscode thunder client.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLVyH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. turns out the jwt isn't what I'm supposed to send to my backend. I used the jwt token to get an access token for the user which I then used to authenticate the user on my backend.